# can't list files in a directory

Tags: coldfusion

I'm using CF 7 and this code is not returning any files:

```
<cfset fileLocation = "\\server\uploader\pass-fail">
<cfdirectory 
  action = "list"
  directory = fileLocation
  name = "pass_fail_files"
  >

     <cfdump var="#pass_fail_files#" expand="yes"   label="files in pass-fail" >

     <cfoutput>#pass_fail_files.name#</cfoutput>
     <cfoutput>#pass_fail_files.directory#</cfoutput>
     <cfoutput>#pass_fail_files.size#</cfoutput>
     <cfoutput>#pass_fail_files.type#</cfoutput>
     <cfoutput>#pass_fail_files.dateLastModified#</cfoutput>
     <cfoutput>#pass_fail_files.attributes#</cfoutput>
     <cfoutput>#pass_fail_files.mode# </cfoutput>
```

I have checked to make sure that the directory indeed has several text files.  But when I run the code, all I get is:

[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/5603/nofiles.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/5603/nofiles.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check to see if directoryExists(fileLocation) returns true or false. The answer depends on the result of that. Is the ColdFusion service running under "SYSTEM" or has an account been created for CF to run as? For that matter, what OS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just tried this:

```
<cfset fileLocation = "\\192.168.8.20\websites">
<cfdirectory 
  action = "list"
  directory = "#fileLocation#"
  name = "pass_fail_files"
  >
<cfdump var="#pass_fail_files#" expand="yes"   label="files in pass-fail" >
```

On CF7, CF8 and Railo, and works everytime.

Notice I updated your code so it uses the directory attribute as **directory = "#fileLocation#"** as opposed to **directory = fileLocation**.

Trying your code, I never got results, but didn't get errors either. Changing it to use **double-quotes** and **hashes** did the trick, as it stopped using it as a variable.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I just tryed to output my data with <cfoutput query="queryname">. But it didn't work. Just <cfloop query="queryname"> worked. With cfoutput i alway got an error like "can't resolve complex datatypes...". Did i forget something or doesn't cfoutput work for cfdirectory output?

Answer (score 2):

My first question would be, does the ColdFusion Service User have read access on folder?

Actually, I think your code should be

`<cfdirectory 
  action = "list"
  directory = "#fileLocation#"
  name = "pass_fail_files"
  >`

I think right now, you're telling it to look in a directory named "fileLocation".

Comment: No, since fileLocation is _not_ in quotes, it is evaluated as a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you've done all the latest CF7 updates/patches/hotfixes..